# PHP & MYSQL: mysqldump skips tables

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I am trying to take full backup of my database using php system function and mysqldump command.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$database = 'db';
$user = 'me';
$pass = 'pass';
$host = 'localhost';
$dir = 'file' . date('Y.m.d_H.m.s') . '.sql.gz';
$tempConfig = tmpfile();
fwrite($tempConfig, "[client]\nhost={$host}\nuser={$user}\npassword={$pass}");
$tempConfigPath = stream_get_meta_data($tempConfig)['uri'];
echo "mysqldump --add-drop-table  --defaults-extra-file={$tempConfigPath} $database  --routines --triggers | gzip  > $dir";
system("mysqldump   --defaults-extra-file={$tempConfigPath} $database | gzip  > $dir");
exit;
```

The code runs fine, but the problem is it skips many tables. it backup 10 of 190+ tables. the last manual backup i took is about 190MB.
Any Assistance or explanation as to why its not backing up the full db will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: It's probably taking too long. I wouldn't run mysqldump directly from PHP as it would run longer than PHP allows to execute. Instead, use PHP to trigger a bash script which does the dump.

Comment: @aynber please explain more.